# Mount USB flash drive to /media/<label>

Tags: mount, usb, media

I did a minimal install of Debian using a USB thumb drive (instead of a DVD) and rebooted my box.

At the console, tty1, I logged in to my user account. I re-plugged in my USB thumb drive that contained the "burned" ISO image of Debian.

/etc/fstab showed that the USB flash drive was mounted at two locations:

```
/dev/sdb1    /media/usb0
/dev/sdb2    /media/usb1
```

How do I mount it so that it shows the following?

```
/dev/sdb1    /media/"Debian GNU/Linux 7.7.0 Wheezy - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20141018-13:06"
```

P.S.: This post arose because a forum member, `owenmck`, claimed to be able to mount it as such. Please see his post at [Media changed: please insert the disk labeled 'Debian GNU/Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125859/media-changed-please-insert-the-disk-labeled-debian-gnu-linux)

Comment: Try the [`udisks (8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/udisks.8) tool.

Comment: @muru According to Debian, the `udisks` package is on my USB thumb drive. But the question is: how to mount the USB flash drive at `tty1` so that my box can find, read and install it?

Answer (score 0):

You just want to mount your usb to a different folder? That folder name apparently contains a `/` which is one of the few characters not allowed, congratulations on finding one! And do you want the `"` characters too?

Either way, changing the middle `/` into a `-` you could do (as root probably):

```
mkdir Debian\ GNU-Linux\ 7.7.0\ Wheezy\ -\ Official\ amd64\ DVD\ Binary-1\ 20141018-13\:06/
```

or

```
mkdir /media/\"Debian\ GNU-Linux\ 7.7.0\ Wheezy\ -\ Official\ amd64\ DVD\ Binary-1\ 20141018-13\:06\"/
```

or with the `"`s

```
mkdir '/media/"Debian GNU-Linux 7.7.0 Wheezy - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20141018-13:06"'
```

And then `umount /dev/sdb1` followed by

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /media/Debian\ GNU-Linux\ 7.7.0\ Wheezy\ -\ Official\ amd64\ DVD\ Binary-1\ 20141018-13\:06/
```

Editing your `/etc/fstab` to change `/media/usb0` into `/media/Debian\ GNU-Linux\ 7.7.0\ Wheezy\ -\ Official\ amd64\ DVD\ Binary-1\ 20141018-13\:06/` should make it permanent

Comment: I wrote the original post above because a forum member named `owenmck` mentioned that he mounted it as such. Please see his post at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125859/media-changed-please-insert-the-disk-labeled-debian-gnu-linux

Comment: @user65787 I'm not sure about that other post or it's question, it's about apt sources or something I'm not super familiar with, looks like he mounted his usb to `/media/Debian 7.5 64 Copyleft FM`, could use single quotes to enclose the spaces if don't want to escape them with `\`. But here I tried to answer your "how to mount to `/media/<label>`" question, I hope it's worked & can mount to whatever label you choose, if so you can select/check-mark it if it's the best

Comment: last comment didn't escape the escape backslash! I'll try again, something funny happens when putting a backslash inside backticks, looks like it "escapes" the last backtick... here "\" or `\ `

Comment: You wrote: `I'm not sure about that other post or it's question, it's about apt sources or something I'm not super familiar with, looks like he mounted his usb to...` That's exactly what I wish to know how to do what he did because then `sudo apt-get install <package-name>` would be able to fetch packages directly from the plugged-in USB flash drive.

Comment: But this Question here is about "Mount USB flash drive to /media/<label>" @user65787

Comment: But in a narrow context. Please see the post scriptum (P.S.) in my original post.

Comment: So if this Question about "Mounting to /media/<label>" has been answered then please select / check-mark as correct. Thanks!